# convert from windows-1256 to utf8 withe iconv php

Tags: type-conversion, iconv

i want to see if the string will convert from windows-1256 to utf-8 befor saving it in data base but the result is not correct

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$text="ÇáÇäÊãÇÁ";
$utf8 = iconv('windows-1256', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $text);
echo $utf8;
?></body>

</html>
```